# Create ionic 3 app with Target SDK version 30 getting error in google play console

Tags: ionic-framework, google-play-console

I am create my app in ionic v3 with Target SDK version 30
when i am upload my apk on google play console i am getting error
"You uploaded an APK with an invalid signature (learn more about signing). Error from apksigner: ERROR: MIN_SIG_SCHEME_FOR_TARGET_SDK_NOT_MET: Target SDK version 30 requires a minimum of signature scheme v2; the APK is not signed with this or a later signature scheme"

When i am making apk with Target SDK version 29 and upload on google play console its upload without any error

i don't no whay google give me an error

create sign in apk proccess are same in Target SDK version 30 or Target SDK version 29 same keystore and all command are same for create sign apk

My command are
ionic cordova build --release android

jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore myappname.keystore app-release-unsigned.apk myapp

zipalign -v 4 app-release-unsigned.apk myappname.apk

Please Check what is wrong on about command and let me know it's argent my client are waiting a Target SDK version 30

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution

i am use this solution for ionic app only using cmd

After zipalign command success apply this command for conver sign apk with signature scheme v2

apksigner sign --v2-signing-enabled false --ks keystore name.keystore signapkname.apk

apksigner sign --ks keystore name.keystore signapkname.apk

apksigner sign --ks keystore name.keystore --ks-key-alias aliasname signapkname.apk

keytool -printcert -jarfile signapkname.apk

apksigner verify -v --print-certs signapkname.apk

apksigner verify -v signapkname.apk

Comment: Thank you so much, this help me a lot!

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution! If you are using a .jks, remove keystore parameter.

Answer (score 13):

After build for release -> jarsigner -> zipalign,
I just need these scripts. To sign the apk with APK Signature Scheme v2:

```
apksigner sign --ks yourkeystore.keystore yourapk.apk
```

To verify the signing

```
apksigner verify -v yourapk.apk
```

Comment: and then zipalign?

Comment: did not work. However the commands in the chosen answer did. Does not really make sense why there can't be one command that does the thing and you have to do jarsigner, zipalign, then 3 commands to sign the zipaligned apk......

Comment: I've edited my answer. After jarsigner and zipalign, I've tried all scripts in the chosen answer, but I think I just need these two scripts from apksigner.

Comment: I may give it a go next time we have to release the app in the store, next sprint. Thanks

Comment: Thank you so much buddy. This really really worked for my team.

Comment: Thank you made my day! I've been looking for this for hours.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this as a quick fix hack
after the zipalign step is done :

> zipalign -v 4 HelloWorld-release-unsigned.apk HelloWorld.apk

I have followed this extra step:

> apksigner sign --ks app.keystore --v1-signing-enabled true --v2-signing-enabled true HelloWorld.apk

*Please note : use the same password you used for the keystore file.
So now you can upload your .apk file or .aab file to play store*